# The request is missing a required parameter: AWS ElasticBeanstalk and Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with [Lucadegasperi's OAuth 2](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel). My API Server is on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, with an SSL cert, and is delivered through AWS Cloudfront distribution.

Cloudfront made it easier to get the https cert on there and save money, as to add the cert directly to the EC2, you'd need expensive Load Balancing.

Anyway, I'm getting the following error through DHC when making a request with an OAuth2 access token to my **production** server, **but having no issues on my localhost**:

> "error": "invalid_request",
>
> "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter."

For prod/local, I first make a request to get the access token (changing the URL accordingly):

```
POST: http://myapp-api.localhost/1.0/oauth/access_token
HEADERS: Content-Type: application/json
BODY: {
  "username" : "my@myemail.com",
  "password" : "password",
  "client_id" : "myclientid",
  "client_secret" : "myclientsecret",
  "grant_type" : "password",
  "refresh_grant" : "refresh_token"
}
```

This gets the access token, which I then use to get a quest successfully:

```
GET: http://myapp-api.localhost/1.0/quests/1
HEADERS: Authorization: Bearer aTNk...
```

Both getting the access token and requesting an OAuth2 protected route, `/quests/1`, on localhost work fine.

But on AWS server, making the same request below results in error above:

```
GET: https://api.myapp.com/1.0/quests/1
HEADERS: Authorization: Bearer zYrA...
```

Comment: in an effort to try and get the same error on your localhost, why don't you turn on https on your localhost api and use a self signed cert?

Comment: Also - what is DHC?